# Apache MINA SNI implementation

Tags: ssl, mina, sni

Has anyone had any experience implementing SNI (Server Name Indication) into Apache MINA's SSLFilter?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we ended up doing was creating a custom SslFilter that extends SslFilter. It turns out if that the SslEngine is supplied with a String peerHost, and a int peerPort, it will take care of the SNI for you. They don't state anything explicitly about SNI in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#SSLEngine%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) but it does seem to work. In our custom SslFilter we overrode the onPreAdd to get the IoSession and set the PEER_ADDRESS attribute to the remoteAddress we wanted. We also override the setRemoteAddr(InetSocketAddress addr) and the Constructor to call super(sslContext, true);

Comment: Thanks for updating with your solution. This is exactly what I need.